# Removing spaces from a variable input using PowerShell 4.0

Tags: string, powershell, variables, spaces, stripping

I've tried a few things already but they don't seem to work for some reason.

Basically what I'm attempting to do is have a user input a value using the 
"Read-host" cmdlet, then strip it of any spaces.

I tried:

```
$answer = read-host
$answer.replace(' ' , '""')
```

And:

```
$answer = read-host
$answer -replace (' ')
```

I'm probably missing something really obvious, but if anyone could help me out or show me an easier way to achieve this I would appreciate it.

I was going to pipeline the variable to a command and strip it in that fashion, but none of the examples I've seen work, although they look much easier.

Comment: `$str = $str.replace(' ','')`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The `Replace` operator means *Replace something with something else*; do not be confused with removal functionality.

Also you should send the result processed by the operator to a variable or to another operator. Neither `.Replace()`, nor `-replace` modifies the original variable.

To remove all spaces, use '*Replace any space symbol with empty string*'

```
$string = $string -replace '\s',''
```

To remove all spaces at the beginning and end of the line, and replace all double-and-more-spaces or tab symbols to spacebar symbol, use

```
$string = $string -replace '(^\s+|\s+$)','' -replace '\s+',' '
```

or the more native `System.String` method

```
$string = $string.Trim()
```

Regexp is preferred, because `' '` means only 'spacebar' symbol, and `'\s'` means 'spacebar, tab and other space symbols'. Note that `$string.Replace()` does 'Normal' replace, and `$string -replace` does RegEx replace, which is more heavy but more functional.

Note that RegEx have some special symbols like dot (`.`), braces (`[]()`), slashes (`\`), hats (`^`), mathematical signs (`+-`) or dollar signs (`$`) that need do be escaped. ( `'my.space.com' -replace '\.','-'` => `'my-space-com'`. A dollar sign with a number (ex `$1`) must be used on a right part with care

```
'2033' -replace '(\d+)',$( 'Data: $1')
Data: 2033
```

UPDATE: You can also use `$str = $str.Trim()`, along with `TrimEnd()` and `TrimStart()`. Read more at [System.String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN page.

Comment: The answer can be confusing for a student/learner because you refer to other replaces besides whitespace.

Answer (score 9):

You're close. You can strip the whitespace by using the `replace` method like this:

`$answer.replace(' ','')`

There needs to be no space or characters between the second set of quotes in the replace method (replacing the whitespace with nothing).

Answer (score 6):

You also have the [Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx), [TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) and [TrimStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx) methods of the [System.String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) class. The trim method will strip whitespace (with a couple of Unicode quirks) from the leading and trailing portion of the string while allowing you to optionally specify the characters to remove.

```
#Note there are spaces at the beginning and end
Write-Host " ! This is a test string !%^ "
 ! This is a test string !%^
#Strips standard whitespace
Write-Host " ! This is a test string !%^ ".Trim()
! This is a test string !%^
#Strips the characters I specified
Write-Host " ! This is a test string !%^ ".Trim('!',' ')
This is a test string !%^
#Now removing ^ as well
Write-Host " ! This is a test string !%^ ".Trim('!',' ','^')
This is a test string !%
Write-Host " ! This is a test string !%^ ".Trim('!',' ','^','%')
This is a test string
#Powershell even casts strings to character arrays for you
Write-Host " ! This is a test string !%^ ".Trim('! ^%')
This is a test string
```

TrimStart and TrimEnd work the same way just only trimming the start or end of the string.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
$answer.replace(' ' , '')
```

or

```
$answer -replace " ", ""
```

if you want to remove all whitespace you can use:

```
$answer -replace "\s", ""
```

Comment: What is the diff between \s and ' ' (first and third example)?

Comment: @Timo - `' '` is a string containing a single space so only that character will be matched. "\s" is a regex matching any whitespace so the third example removes all whitespace and not just spaces.

Comment: Thanks Lee so \s is much saver to remove all spaces than ' ' because you can easily type 2 spaces while your intent was just one.

Answer (score 1):

If the string is

```
$STR = 'HELLO WORLD'
```

and you want to remove the empty space between 'HELLO' and 'WORLD'

```
$STR.replace(' ','')
```

`replace` takes the string and replaces white space with empty string (of length 0), in other words the white space is just deleted.