# how to remove multiple spaces in multiple file names in a folder in windows 10 using powershell

Tags: powershell

For example, how can I change multiple file names in a folder: which are in the format "  New     file   " to "New file" in windows 10 using powershell

Comment: Need to remove trailing and leading spaces, multiple spaces in between words in multiple file names in a folder using powershell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing spaces from a variable thats user inputted in PowerShell 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355760/removing-spaces-from-a-variable-thats-user-inputted-in-powershell-4-0)

Answer (score 1):

From https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/18/trim-your-strings-with-powershell/

The easiest Trim method to use is the `Trim()` method. It is very useful, and it is the method I use most. It easily removes all whitespace characters from the beginning and from the end of a string. This is shown here:

```
PS C:\> $string = " a String "
PS C:\> $string.Trim()
# => a String
```

The method is that easy to use. I just call `Trim()` on any string, and it will clean it up. Unfortunately, the previous output is a bit hard to understand, so let me try a different approach. This time, I obtain the length of the string before I trim it, and I save the resulting string following the trim operation back into a variable. I then obtain the length of the string a second time. Here is the command:

```
$string = " a String "
$string.Length
# => 10
$string = $string.Trim()
$string
# => a String
$string.Length
# => 8
```

Comment: The `.Trim()` string method only removes leading/trailing space.  If extra spaces need to be removed from within the string, you can do as follows: `-split $string -join ' '`

Comment: Okay, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp" -Recurse -file | Rename-Item -NewName {"{0}{1}" -f $_.BaseName.Trim(), $_.Extension}
```