# How to remove leading and trailing spaces in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Where I run the following command:

`Write-Host '"os":"'(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Caption'",'`

I get the following output:

`"os":" Microsoft Windows 10 Pro ",`

How to remove the leading and trailing space in the output??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing spaces from a variable input using PowerShell 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355760/removing-spaces-from-a-variable-input-using-powershell-4-0)

Comment: no, the .replace(" ","") is removing spaces between words, not from start and end

Comment: As an aside: [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it _by itself_; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or use `Write-Output $value`, though that is rarely needed); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375)

Comment: yeah, earlier i was using write-output to store output in file but for some reason, i need to get value on only prompt screen. so that's why, i used write-host.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you're passing 3 distinct string arguments to `Write-Host`, the cmdlet then separates them with spaces:

```
Write-Host '"os":"'(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Caption'",'
           \______/\______________________________________________________/\__/
```

Change to

```
Write-Host """os"":""$((Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Caption)"","
```

Here, we create 1 (one!) string with correctly escaped quotation marks, and `Write-Host` won't attempt to add any whitespace.

---

If the goal is to produce JSON, I'd suggest constructing a new object and letting `ConvertTo-Json` take care of the rest:

```
$data = [pscustomobject]@{
  os = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Caption
}

$data |ConvertTo-Json
```

The output of which will be something like:

```
{
    "os":  "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise"
}
```

Comment: Nicely done; also worth mentioning that `Write-Host` should never be used to output _data_.